# How to Define Complex Concepts and Subclass that Inherits Properties of Superclass in Protege Owl

Tags: xml, artificial-intelligence, owl, ontology, protege

My Question Title might look complex and that's because it is two questions in one:

1. Firstly, I want to know how I can define complex concepts that have 'AND' , 'OR'  and maybe restrictions in its definition. I know how to create a class in protege but what I want to know is how to give it the definition. For example, I have a concept called Bad Boys and it's description is as follows:

BadBoy = Boy {And} hasGirlFriend.Girlfriend {And} rapesGirl.Girl {And} doDrug.Drug

How do I achieve that conjunction or disjunction since I can't see anything as such in the protege menu. I can only create an axiom as simple as Boy hasGirlFriend.Girlfriend but I don't know how to combine complex definition and put it inside a single concept using protege.

2. Secondly, when I create a class Person with properties hasName and hasAge, I expect that a subclass Man will inherit those properties of Person and I do not have to specify subclass Man as a domain for those properties again. Instead, even after starting my reasoner, I don't see the properties of the superclass under the uses of the subclass. Am I doing something wrong?

Kindly help please and let me know if you need more explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I don't have problems doing above in description logics, what I want to know is how to do it in Protege. I use protege 4 and Hermit Reasoner.

Comment: You have to use the class expression editor, i.e. click on the class in the hierarchy and on the right-hand side of the UI click on on the `+` icon next to `Equivalent To`.